# Non privileged user doesn't recognize ruby gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rpm

I'm trying to build an rpm of the compass gem. This src.rpm requires some gems like rake, haml and so on. I installed these gems as root but when building as a normal user it still requires the dependencies.

When trying something like which rake it knows where to find the gem as normal user but still it seems not to recognize it. Als gem install as normal user ends up with a Permission Denied message. Anyone knows why it does not find these gems?

Comment: I guess you created them as root with bundle install and you do not have read permission. Try to find the gems and set read permission for all. Tell me if it works out!

Comment: I did a chown on /usr/local/rvm/bin/rake so the user mockbuild gets the root rights but even after that it doesn't seem to work..